# Problem in Basic Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers

I want to prove that if
$$E_{b,y} = \{ r\in \Bbb Q |\; b^r\leq y \}$$
for $b\in \Bbb R^{>1}$ and $y\in \Bbb R^{>0}$

then, $\sup E_{b,y}$ is the unique solution to the equation
$$b^x = y$$

I want to prove this with no higher theory and without using the fact that $b^x$ is continuous.

Also, note:
$$b^x := \sup\{b^r |\; r \leq x \;  \forall r\in \Bbb Q\}$$

where $b^r = (b^m)^{1/n}$ if $r = \frac m n$, $m,n\in \Bbb Z \quad n > 0$

or in other words, $b^r$ is the unique $n$th root of $b\cdot b \cdot b \cdots$ (m times)

I can easily prove that if a solution to the exponential equation exists it is unique, but I am having trouble proving that the supremum of the set I have constructed is the solution.

Comment: Some copy-editing: \sup, \mid, \cdots

Comment: So you'd rather write $sup E$ than $\sup E$?

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you should also prove that $E_{b,y}$ is necessarily bounded above, so that $\sup E_{b,y}$ makes sense. I leave that to you. Also, your definition of $b^x$ is incorrect, at present. It should read $$b^x=\sup\{b^r\mid r\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }r<x\},\tag{$\star$}$$ or something to that effect.

Now, for such $b,y,$ let $\alpha=\sup E_{b,y}.$ There are only three possibilities to consider, by trichotomy:

1. $b^\alpha=y$ (in which case we're done),
2. $b^\alpha<y,$ or
3. $b^\alpha>y.$

Now, the third case can't happen, because if so, then there is some $r'\in\Bbb Q$ with $r'<\alpha$ such that $b^{r'}>y.$ By definition of $\alpha,$ $r'$ is not an upper bound of $E_{b,y},$ meaning that there is some $r\in E_{b,y}$ such that $r'<r.$ But then $b^{r'}<b^r$ (why?), which is a contradiction, since $b^r\le y<b^{r'}.$

To prove that the second case can't happen, you should prove that if $x<y,$ then there is some $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $x<b^r\le y$ (from which we can again derive a contradiction if we assume the second case holds).

See what you can do. If you have issues, let me know, and I'll respond as soon as I am able.

Comment: Yeah I did all that, I can't prove that there is a b^r <= y though.

Comment: Well, let's suppose not. Then for all $r\in\Bbb Q,$ we have $b^r>y.$ Consequently, $b^{-r}<\frac1y$ for all $r\in\Bbb Q,$ and in particular, $b^n<\frac1y$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. Then for all $q,r\in\Bbb Q$ with $1<q<b$ and $0<r<y,$ we have $q^n<\frac1r$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z.$ (Why?) Fix such a $q$ and such an $r,$ and see if you can derive a contradiction.

Comment: $b^n < \frac 1 y$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z$ can't be true...

Comment: You're right. Can you prove it?

Comment: y>0 but no matter how small y is, b^n>1/y for some n big enough

Comment: Again, true. If you can prove it, then it follows that $b^{-n}<y,$ so you've found $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $b^r<y.$

Comment: ohh, ok i think i get it thx

Comment: I don't get why you say that for all $r\in \Bbb Q$ in your first comment, I don't believe that is the opposite of what we are trying to prove.

Comment: Well, what you're *trying* to prove is that there is some $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $b^r\le y.$ So, to assume the negation, there is *no such* $r.$ Consequently, *every* $r\in\Bbb Q$ has the property that $b^r\not\leq y,$ that is, $b^r>y.$

Comment: No, I'm trying to find $x<b^r<y$

Comment: Put in formal terms, the negation of $$\exists r\in\Bbb Q:b^r\le y$$ is $$\forall r\in\Bbb Q, b^r>y.$$

Comment: Just because b^r<y doesn't mean its greater than x

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, misread the first comment

Comment: I thought I had it, but I made a mistake. Can you explain more carefully each step?

Comment: Each step of which part?